# Why does my regex pattern allow digits?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have tried creating a regex pattern that matches only letters and allows a whitespace:

```
import re
user_input = raw_input('Input: ')

if re.match('[A-Za-z ]', user_input):
    print user_input
```

However,

When inputting `o888`, or something similar, a match seems to still occur

Answer (score 5):

That happens because your regex allows *partial* matches.

Use

```
if re.match('[A-Za-z ]*$', user_input):
                      ^^
```

to anchor the pattern at the end and match 0+ chars. As [**`re.match`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) anchors the pattern at the start of the string, the `^` anchor is not necessary, but `$` - end of string - is required to enforce the full string match.

If you do not want to allow an empty string, use `+` quantifier - *one or more occurrences* - rather than `*` (*zero or more occurrences*).

Comment: Thanks. Would that apply for any regex pattern using re.match?

Comment: Any regex is anchored at the start of the string with `re.match` - that applies to each regex. Even if you use `re.M` flag and add `^` anchor (start of string/line), the match will only be looked for at the start of the whole string. [*Note that even in `MULTILINE` mode, `re.match()` will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)